# ERROR: "._android-support-v4.jar" in project FacebookSDK

Tags: android, facebook

Help needed!!!!  Stuck for 2 weeks on this and help needed.

I've recently imported the facebook sdk for android and its projects into my workspace.  It shows up errors and the problems:

> Archive for required library: '/home/Documents/facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2.b/facebook/libs/._android-support-v4.jar' in project 'FacebookSDK' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

And the samples get errors along the line of:

> The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library '/home/Documents/facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2.b/facebook/bin/facebooksdk.jar'

The things I have done following the other discussions without any success are

cleaned project

set the Facebook SDK as library

looked at the build path section and added external jar consisting of facebook/libs

imported fb sdk like 20 times and into different folders.

made sure my java compiler was 1.6

HELP would be very greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: '/home/Documents/facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2.b/facebook/libs/._android-support-v4.jar This path looks weird. Why the "._" before your file?

Comment: Check which directory you're downloading to

Comment: i put the Facebook root directory next to the android ADT directory (which contains my SDK and eclipse) in the Documents directory

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take the lastest version of `android-support-v4.jar` (in your sdk environement : `sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar`) and replace in your project and library project do not create conflict.

Comment: , do you mean copying the sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar file into the facebook/libs/ folder?  And deleting the facebook/libs/android-support-v4.jar file?

Comment: yes I do. Replace the lib by the same jar and the lastest (so generaly, it's the jar of your sdk).

Comment: Don't Forget to mark your question t resolved if the solution is found. Thank

Answer (score 0):

The steps to importing a library are:

1. Download the library
2. Place the library in the libs folder of the project.
3. Build the project
4. **Do Not** attempt to import the library using some import wizard.

I suspect either your download was corrupted, and you need to do it again, or you put the file into the wrong directly.

Comment: I downloaded the the root folder containing the fb sdk and samples into a directory.  I then followed your advice in copying the samples and fb sdk into the libs of a newly created project.  I built the project.  Everything worked without errors but the project doesn't recognize when i create a facebook object.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the android.support.v4 versions are different, take the one from your project and replace the one in the Facebook sdk lib folder, it should dismiss the clash.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, I think you are not able to compile once you add the SDK to your project. Do you get an error saying unable to run as library?
If so that means you have included this as library and create your project as a library to be used further. It is a common mistake that I have seen many people do when they try to import a library to use and tick mark the checkbox is Library. This actually means you want this project to be treated as a library for future use. Just try to add the SDK and do not tick mark the checkbox and this project will run fine. 
Many forums will just tell you to tick that checkbox and you will be stuck on this error for long time.

For any .jar file related issues you have to make the .jars files compatible as there hashing a problem and the two jars are not compatible with each other (a version issue).