# not detecting jar file

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook-sdk-3.1

I want to use the Facebook authentication in my application.For that I have downloaded Facebook SDK. I am trying to run one sample application in that. But, getting the error

The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library `'/home/linux/android/sdk/tools/support/annotations.jar'`

I have updated my SDK to 19 but getting the same error.

Comment: ... The error is fairly straight forward... Are the supporting resources where they are supposed to be? Are they also being copied to the output directory?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061986/missing-annotations-jar

Comment: @TalhaQ I have tried all these.But didn't work for me

Comment: Just clean your project,restart your eclipse and try once more.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841432/resolved-error-android-support-v4-jar-in-project-facebooksdk?rq=1

Comment: I am already done with cleaning and restarting the eclipse