# ._android-support-v4.jr cannot be read

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

I import my older project, and i give this error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/Janko/workspace/gb android zdrojáky/girlsapp/client/GirlBom/libs/._android-support-v4.jar' in project 'GirlBom' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file   GirlBom     Build path  Build Path Problem

i try this -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841432/resolved-error-android-support-v4-jar-in-project-facebooksdk#_=_)
but dont help me. I try reinstall eclipse. Try Android Tools -> Add Support library. But still nothing.

Here is picutre, that the library is there:

[image: project]

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Try changing your workspace.

Comment: create new workspace and change ?

Comment: Yes correct try that way, as it is showing error from your workspace's location. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Just a guess, but try switching to a path which contains neither spaces nor accented characters, as things like that have historically caused many problems.  Also make sure the referenced file actually exists, and is at that location.

Comment: this does not help ...

Comment: Any moore ideas? i am desperate, becouse i need working with this app but i can not build it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution, i delete hidden files in libs folder which start with "._", in workspace in my project. And then clean project.
And Done